# Is there a better way to correct errors in Adobe Acrobat's OCR results?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, ocr

I'm using OCR Text Recognition integrated into Adobe Acrobat Pro 8 to produce an (invisible) searchable text overlay for text pages I have scanned. This is very neat for copying some phrases to the clipboard or for text searching.

In some cases, Adobe does a rather poor job and in some cases it just produces a few typos, making the corresponding words or sentences un-searchable. In the [Adobe Forums, user strontium87](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3205365#3205365) explains that you can manually show the text and then modify with the Touchup Text tool, before setting it to invisible again. Since this method is quite cumbersome - does anyone know of an easier way to do this? Maybe with an external tool?

Comment: Vaguely related question: http://superuser.com/questions/141628/good-free-ocr-with-gui-for-correcting-mistakes-for-windows

Comment: If Adobe's way doesn't cut this, you'll need another way to do this. This could be considered a duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Acrobat Pro have substantially improved the workflow.  With Acrobat Pro XI (and I believe X), you first do the text recognition, and can then go through suspect errors by clicking Tools->Text Recognition->Find First Suspect or Find All Suspects. This will display the text overlay for the words and let you correct things. When you're done with it, the image returns and the text is hidden again.